# How to change style in material-ui table pagination

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the way material-ui displays table pagination.
Currently what material-ui shows is like this

[image]

I want to change it like this

[image]

Is it possible to style it this way?

Comment: This can only be possible by either `overriding the table` component or `creating your own table component`.

Comment: Okk, Thanks I will try using react-table

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by override the pagination component
By default, pagination uses the TablePagination component that is optimized for handling tabular data. This demo replaces it with the Pagination component.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { DataGrid, useGridSlotComponentProps } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { useDemoData } from '@mui/x-data-grid-generator';
import Pagination from '@material-ui/lab/Pagination';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
});

function CustomPagination() {
  const { state, apiRef } = useGridSlotComponentProps();
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Pagination
      className={classes.root}
      color="primary"
      count={state.pagination.pageCount}
      page={state.pagination.page + 1}
      onChange={(event, value) => apiRef.current.setPage(value - 1)}
    />
  );
}

export default function CustomPaginationGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: 'Commodity',
    rowLength: 100,
    maxColumns: 6,
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        pagination
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        components={{
          Pagination: CustomPagination,
        }}
        {...data}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```